# Why doesn't my SAS array statement reference the expected variables?

Tags: datetime, sas, date-difference

I am trying to find the number of hours between a departure(Out) and when the next visit(In) occurred in SAS.

My dataset(SAS dataset) looks like this. Variables In and Out are datetime variables.

```
ID  In1             In2             Out1            Out2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   14AUG12:10:27   16AUG12:08:38   14AUG12:16:25   16AUG12:09:38
2   08AUG12:14:41   09AUG12:07:37   08AUG12:22:14   09AUG12:08:58
3   08AUG12:08:54   09AUG12:23:45   08AUG12:14:04   10AUG12:02:55
4   27AUG12:06:41   27AUG12:10:42   27AUG12:09:45   27AUG12:12:17
5   07AUG12:23:16   09AUG12:22:13   07AUG12:23:16   10AUG12:15:59
```

I want to calculate the difference between In2 and Out1, that is I want In2 - Out1 in hours(the difference between when they were out and when they returned again). I decided to do this over a loop, since I have many records. I have varied In's and Out's for all records (I don't know this before hand). In this particular dataset I have up to In33 and Out33.

My code is

```
data counts;

set mydata;

array in _numeric_;

array out _numeric_;

do k = 1 to 32;

time = intck('hour', out[k], in[k+1]);

if time >= 0 and time<= 72 then output;

end;
run;
```

My problem here is the accuracy of the number of hours that I get as output. For this particular data shown above, I get time as 46, 17, 39, 4 and 52 hours respectively for ID 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. But the times should be 40, 9, 33, 1, and 47 hours respectively for ID 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Try defining the arrays with the proper variables.  ARRAY IN IN:; ARRAY OUT OUT:;

Comment: Is your ID column actually in your data set? If ID is numeric is that getting picked up in the "array in" and "array out"? If you are thinking you are missing the ID because you are starting k = 1 and not k=0, that won't help because SAS arrays start at 1.

Comment: IN and OUT are the proper variable names.

ID is in the dataset.

IN and OUT are original variables that have multiple records for each ID; I transposed them to have only one record for each ID to get In1, In2 etc.

I do not know length of each array beforehand, but both IN and OUT always have the same length.

I will try your suggesting by finding a way to explicitly declare the arrays @Snorehorse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two arrays are identical because you are declaring them equal to all the numeric variables in your mydata set. You have to name them as per data_null_'s comment, or more explicitly:

```
array in in1-in33;
array out out1-out33;
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the arrays and I now get the required accuracy. This is how I did it

```
data counts;
set mydata;
array Ins {*} In: ;
array Outs {*} Out: ;
do k = 1 to dim(ins) - 1;
time = intck('hour', outs[k], ins[k+1]);
if time >= 0 and time <= 72 then output;
end;
run;
```

Thank you for your suggestions, it helped.